# How to serialize a list of objects of a class that contains a list of a struct

Tags: c#, json, jsonserializer

I have a list of objects of a class that is composed of simple properties and a property that is a list of a struct

```
struct UGdata
{
    public int ID;
    public float curGen;
    public float nomGen;
}
internal class PlantData
{
    public float Level {get;set;}
    public string UGName {get;set;}
    public List<UGData> UGs {get;set;}
}
```

Inside my code i fill data with sqlserver informations i have something like this:

```
List<PlantData> MyData = new List<PlantData>
for(int i=0; i<n; i++)
{    
     PlantData info = new PlantData();
     for(int j=0; j<m;j++)
     {
        UGData data = new UGData();
        //fill the UG data properties
        info.UGs.Add(data)
        //fill other info properties
     }
     MyData.Add(info)
}
```

And in the end i want serialize these informations: (I'm using System.Texts.Json)

```
string Jsonoutput = JsonSerializer.Serialize(MyData)
```

The output come from without struct informations, like this:

```
{
    "Level":10
    "UGName":A
    "UGs": []
},
{
    "Level":30
    "UGName":B
    "UGs": []
}
```

I have to write a specific Serializer for this structure? I read some threads with similar options but I couldn't make any progress. Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You should make all types `public` + make sure that you use properties everywhere, so with `{ get; set; }`.

Comment: Thanks.! Putting get/set in the struct properties it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.Text.Json` does not serialize fields by default. You need either to use properties:

```cs
struct UGdata
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public float curGen { get; set; }
    public float nomGen { get; set; }
}
```

Or [include fields explicitly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/how-to?pivots=dotnet-8-0#include-fields) either via serializer options:

```cs
string jsonOutput = JsonSerializer.Serialize("MyData", new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    IncludeFields = true
});
```

Or by marking fields with corresponding attribute.

```
struct UGdata
{
    [JsonInclude]
    public int ID;
    [JsonInclude]
    public float curGen;
    [JsonInclude]
    public float nomGen;
}
```